# Comparing previous 7 days, to the previous 7 days before that in one table from a single date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking to to sum 7 days of a metric, and 7 days prior to that as a metric with relative to a date.

for example:

```
select 
    dim_date.actual_date, 
    sum(fact.metric) as previous 7daysfromactualdate, 
    sum(fact.metric) as previous 8-15fromactualdate,
from 
    fact
join dim_date on dim_date.date_key = fact.date_key
where dim_date.actual_date between @p_start_date and @p_end_date
group by date
```

I know it's not a lot of code or refering tables would I need to create two CTEs?

Comment: Please provide a [MRE] i.e. sample data, desired results as well as your attemp.

Comment: I seconf @DaleK. Where does `date` come from?

Comment: More information is needed.  Do you have data on every day, for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have exactly one row for every preceding date, you can use a windowed `SUM`:

```sql
select 
    d.actual_date, 
    sum(sum(fact.metric)) over
        (order by d.actual_date rows between 7 preceding and 1 preceding) as [previous 7daysfromactualdate], 
    sum(sum(fact.metric)) over
        (order by d.actual_date rows between 15 preceding and 8 preceding) as [previous 8-15fromactualdate],
from 
    fact f
join dim_date d on d.date_key = f.date_key
where d.actual_date between @p_start_date and @p_end_date
group by d.actual_date
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this

```sql
select
sum(case when datediff(day, date, getdate()) <= 7 then metric else 0) as "previous 7 days", 
sum(case when datediff(day, date, getdate()) between 8 and 15 then metric else 0) as "previous 8-15 days"
from fact
join dim_date on dim_date.date_key = fact.date_key
where datediff(day, date, getdate()) <= 15
```

Your data, number of rows, indexes etc. I have no idea about it, so the `where` statement is implemented to avoid performance issues. Because you use it for a maximum of 15 days.